# Why is the speed of queries to the sqlite-based decreases?

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2

There is a project to work with the database sqlite.

My local machine: computer - I5, RAM - 4GB, SSD-disk.
Server - Intel Xeon E3-1220v2 / SSD / RAM 16 Gb

php version 7.0.10 locally and on a server 7.0.8

The project is one and the same thing locally, on a server. But the speed of the job is almost 2 times differ.

Version locally sqlite - 3.8.11, but on a server 3.11.1. I do not think that this question, but still.

The essence of the job in the system - search for existing values, if it is not adding new value. And after the 10K record the values ​​in the table entry and search of new begins to slowly sink (on the server). to 20k (records) the addition rate and compared with the search start local data differs 2-3.
Data read portions through "batch", writing also for 100 (batchinsert) portions
parameter is used to quickly write:

PRAGMA synchronous=0

PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL

PRAGMA count_changes=OFF

I use a transaction, all operations are read and search are performed in a single transaction

**What can be the reason for such a subsidence speed in the project on the server?**

Comment: Show the database schema, the slow query, and its [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output.

Comment: on the server and on the local machine one and the same db. I transfered my aplication from local machine to server and run, and I see this result.

Comment: for example:
on server - 1000000 inserts in 8.338 secs (119934.9 q/s)
local machine - 1000000 inserts in 17.291 secs (57834.3 q/s)
code - http://pastebin.com/CFWd1DAw

Answer (score 0):

The speed of which your database will return data to you is based on multiple factors, but in  your case  there's 2 that seem to be the most relevant.

The first one you already mentioned yourself, the capacity of the system the server runs on. It's obvious that a system that isn't very performant cannot perform better than a system that has a bigger capacity. This means you could scale up your server to make your server run faster.

However, you mention that around 10k records in your database, it is starting to slow down. This suggests that you do not have good indexes in your tables, which means your database's searches will perform slower. It's a good idea to think about indices on your database before you start to fill it up entirely.

I'm actually not sure if SqlLite supports indexing on columns, but if it does you should be fine there. Otherwise you might want to stop using a silly SqlLite database and start using a big boy database such as MySql database which supports much more efficient ways to search, index, and add data.

Comment: Indices in the tables is, they are used in the search. database structure the same. Read and write speed drives also about the same (comparing the local machine and the server). So the question is not in the iron is not in the database.

Comment: in the server, sqlite querys executing slower, why ?

Comment: Because it's a smaller lightweight tool that is not used for it's performance, but rather for its ease to use. Some developers choose to use a sqlite at the start of their development process, and later upgrade to a large powerful database. You could compare it to moving. You can start moving small stuff with your bike, it's easy to park and costs barely anything. But when you actually start to move the big stuff, you call a moving company with their big powerful trucks.